# How do I authenticate into an Azure hosted webservice from Dynamics CRM online?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online, xrm

The Problem: From CRM, we need to call a webservice and display the results using a webresource.  I would like this call to be made using ajax so the UI is somewhat user friendly/responsive.  The webservice is hosted in Azure and can either be an Http triggered function or an App Service web API.

I have seen many examples of creating services in Azure that can authenticate into and access CRM data.  But I haven't been able to find examples where CRM authenticates into Azure.  I am looking for something along these lines [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in js webresource using Ajax call to invoke Azure hosted REST api & consume that response in there.

[Similar discussion in community](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/276186)

You can use MSAL.js to acquire token & use it in authorization header with the below sample code.

```
var _retrieveCategories = function () {
var urlPath = "xyz.azurewebsites.net/.../GetCategories”;
$.ajax({
url: urlPath,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
async: false,
crossDomain: true,
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
          return JSHelper.toJson(data);
},
error: function () {
}
})
.done(function (data, status, jqxhr) {
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand the ajax call portion, but I'm looking for an example of the actual call to MSAL (including keyvault if possible) for the authentication piece.